# how to bind variable name to df

Tags: r

I have a list of list like below:

```
lst<-list(Demographics = list(`101-01-101` = structure(list(SubjectID = "101-01-101", 
    BRTHDTC = "1953-07-07", SEX = "Female"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `101-02-102` = structure(list(
    SubjectID = "101-02-102", BRTHDTC = "1963-07-02", SEX = "Female"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `101-03-103` = structure(list(
    SubjectID = "101-03-103", BRTHDTC = "1940-09-11", SEX = "Male"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), DiseaseStatus = list(
    `101-01-101` = structure(list(SubjectID = "101-01-101", DSDT = "2016-03-14", 
        DSDT_P = NA_character_), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame")), `101-02-102` = structure(list(SubjectID = "101-02-102", 
        DSDT = "2017-04-04", DSDT_P = NA_character_), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `101-03-103` = structure(list(
        SubjectID = character(0), DSDT = character(0), DSDT_P = character(0)), row.names = integer(0), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))), Visits = list(`101-01-101` = structure(list(
    SubjectID = "101-01-101", Visit = "Screening: -28 Days to Day 1", 
    VISND = NA_character_), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), `101-02-102` = structure(list(SubjectID = character(0), 
    Visit = character(0), VISND = character(0)), row.names = integer(0), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), `101-03-103` = structure(list(SubjectID = "101-03-103", 
    Visit = "Screening: -28 Days to Day 1", VISND = NA_character_), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))))
```

I would like to bind variables' name to each df as first row, how should I do it?  I have code as:

```
lst1<-map(lst, function(x) map(x, ~rbind(names(.x), .x)))
```

however it get sth like this where it add .x to the variable name when the df have no input:

[image]

[image]

How should I correct this?
I want it to be:

[image]

Additional question:

If we use `rbind` on following, why it count this df has no names?

[image]

To me , it looks like we have variables with name SubjectID, Visit, VISND.

Comment: But the variable name is just the subjectID, why do you need two similar columns?

Comment: I need those to bind with variable labels.  very strange setting. :P why it is df instead of tibble like the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(lst, function(x) map(x,  
    ~ bind_rows(setNames(as.list(names(.x)), names(.x)), .x)))
```

-ouptut

```
$Demographics
$Demographics$`101-01-101`
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX   
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX   
2 101-01-101 1953-07-07 Female

$Demographics$`101-02-102`
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX   
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX   
2 101-02-102 1963-07-02 Female

$Demographics$`101-03-103`
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX  
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>
1 SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX  
2 101-03-103 1940-09-11 Male 


$DiseaseStatus
$DiseaseStatus$`101-01-101`
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID  DSDT       DSDT_P
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 SubjectID  DSDT       DSDT_P
2 101-01-101 2016-03-14 <NA>  

$DiseaseStatus$`101-02-102`
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID  DSDT       DSDT_P
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 SubjectID  DSDT       DSDT_P
2 101-02-102 2017-04-04 <NA>  

$DiseaseStatus$`101-03-103`
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  SubjectID DSDT  DSDT_P
  <chr>     <chr> <chr> 
1 SubjectID DSDT  DSDT_P
```

Comment: It looks like binding at the wrong place.  the sub list now in the same list.

Comment: Yes, This one works. May I ask why my old codes add `.x` to the variable names? It works with the df with values, but not for NULL df.

Comment: What if I want to use `rbind`. Is it doable?

Comment: @Stataq it is because you are doing `rbind.data.frame` which does use `check.names` and append `X.` if there is no names.  You can have a named vector

Comment: For `101-02-02`'s Visit, does that count as a df without value? Why it count it as `no names`?

Comment: @Stataq sorry, didn't understand your question

Comment: I just add the picture at the end of my post. hopefully that can explain my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234790/discussion-between-stataq-and-akrun).